# API requests within a PHP foreach loop results in laggy page load

Tags: php, youtube, page-load-time

I'm calling a request to the YouTube or Vimeo API on every page item within my loop (currently only 15 items). This works fine but the page load is considerably laggy. Are there any methods to speed this process up? Any examples would be great.

```
foreach ($videos as $video) {

     if ($video->getAttribute('video_id_youtube')) {

          $video_id = $video->getAttribute('video_id_youtube');
          $youtube = $json->decode($fh->getContents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id='.$video_id.'&key=AIzaSyDED8cj2zy37JETK15jwaS5JBkTyJSd9yZ%20&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status'));
          $time = strtotime($youtube->items[0]->snippet->publishedAt);
          $time_elapsed = $phph->ago($time);
          $published_time = $time_elapsed .' ago';
          $views = number_format($youtube->items[0]->statistics->viewCount) . ' views';
          $poster = $youtube->items[0]->snippet->thumbnails->high->url;

     } elseif ($video->getAttribute('video_id_vimeo')) {

          $video_id = $video->getAttribute('video_id_vimeo');
          $vim = $json->decode($fh->getContents('http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/'.$video_id.'.json'));
          $vim_time = strtotime($vim[0]->upload_date);
          $vim_time_elapsed = $phph->ago($vim_time);
          $published_time = $vim_time_elapsed .' ago';
          $views = number_format($vim[0]->stats_number_of_plays) . ' views';
          $poster = $vim[0]->thumbnail_medium;

     }

}
```

Comment: run the jobs in parallel, or see if the api allows multiple requests in a single call. e.g. instead of "fetch me record #1", maybe it allows "fetch me records #1,2,3,4,5"

Answer (score 2):

You could run your query to the APIs in a cron every n minutes, cache it (e.g. in a MySQL database) and only display the cached information (which should load fast) on your website.

Answer (score 0):

It seams to me that it's always getting really slow when you/i are calling api's.. haven'd tried vimeo, but facebook and youtube gets really slow. When I find the work-around for it. i'll let you know

Comment: www.youtube.com/watch?v=WrjwaqZfjIY

Answer (score 0):

This is not testet but based on the Idea of "kije" just without cron job.
The script will cache the requested JSON for one day, that means that it's loading way faster, than making a request every single time.

In the variable `$cacheTime` you can easily define, how long the JSON will be cached.

```
// how many seconds the file should be cached
$cacheTime = 86400;

// path to your cache directory
$cacheDir = "/path/to/your/cachefolder/";

foreach ($videos as $video) {

    if ($video->getAttribute('video_id_youtube')) {

         $video_id = $video->getAttribute('video_id_youtube');
         $filename = $cacheDir.$video_id.".json";

         // NOT tested: ( filemtime( $filename ) > ( time() - $cacheTime ) )
         // but you should get the idea?
         if( file_exists( $filename ) && ( filemtime( $filename ) > ( time() - $cacheTime ) ) ) {
             $youtube = $json->decode( file_get_contents( $filename ) );
         } else {
             $youtubeJSON = $fh->getContents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id='.$video_id.'&key=AIzaSyDED8cj2zy37JETK15jwaS5JBkTyJSd9yZ%20&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status');
             $youtube = $json->decode( $youtubeJSON );
             // cache the file
             file_put_contents( $filename, $youtubeJSON );
         }

         $time = strtotime($youtube->items[0]->snippet->publishedAt);
         $time_elapsed = $phph->ago($time);
         $published_time = $time_elapsed .' ago';
         $views = number_format($youtube->items[0]->statistics->viewCount) . ' views';
         $poster = $youtube->items[0]->snippet->thumbnails->high->url;

    }
```